# How to remove words which contain non-alphabetic using Regex python？

Tags: python, regex

Suppose there is a list `['Hello','@sdfss','sdfh787s','World']`.
How to delete all the words which contain non-alphabetic in this list?
Using Regex in python.
The result should be

```
['Hello','World']
```

Comment: Also, why is regex a requirement; what's wrong with just `isalpha` here?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need regular expressions, just [`isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha):

```
import re
s = ['Hello','@sdfss','sdfh787s','World']
s = [i for i in s if i.isalpha()]
print(s)
```

Output:

```
['Hello', 'World']
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you really don't need regex.  You can perform faster than re. But still if you want to do with re following is solution.

import re
s = ['Hello','@sdfss','sdfh787s','World'] # copied from above solution 
print [i for i in s if re.match(r'[A-Za-z]+$', i) ]